# When to use the full and the conditional likelihood

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, method-comparison

In the context of estimating parameters of a time series model, we may consider either the full likelihood or the conditional likelihood. I was wondering

> > in what situations the full likelihood is significantly better than the conditional likelihood?

By full likelihood, I mean $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = f(x_1)f(x_2|x_1)\ldots f(x_n|x_{n-1},\ldots,x_1)$, while conditional likelihood only considers $f(x_2,\ldots,x_n|x_1) = f(x_2|x_1)f(x_3|x_2,x_1)\ldots f(x_n|x_{n-1},\ldots,x_1)$.

Answer (score -1):

Hi: Notice that the initial equation you wrote [ except that it should be $f(x_1, \ldots x_{n}) = f(x_{n} | x_1, \ldots x_{n-1}) * f(x_1, \ldots x_{n-1})$]  is a product of a full and a conditional. This is the technique used in building likelihoods for time series models. Harvey calls it the prediction error decomposition but it's really just the full likelihood using the product of the conditionals. So, for example, say you had four terms, $x_0$ $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$. Then, the full likelihood would be
$f(x_0) * f(x_1| x_0) * f(x_2|x_1,x_0) * f(x_3| x_2,x_1, x_0)$. So, for time series models, the full likelihood is used but it's constructed using the conditionals. The pure full likelihood ( without using the conditionals ) is generally not useful because usually the response is not IID so it's not possible to not use the conditionals.